# Allow multiple XDMCP sessions (local and remote) for the same user

Tags: centos, ssh, x11, remote-desktop, xdmcp

Currently, on our CentOS 7 machines, we are able to log in to the `usera` account on the physical CentOS machine and also access the same `usera` account remotely via **XDMCP** using **XMing**.

I performed the same setup steps from our CentOS 7 machine on our new AlmaLinux 8.8 machine and I am not able to have the same functionality. Currently, on the AlmaLinux machine if I'm physically logged in to `usera`, I am not able to remotely access `usera` and vice versa.

Are they any methods in the RHEL8 umbrella that will allow for multiple XDMCP sessions on a single user?